# Excel, cycle through columns and rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel table that calculates how many materials we need to order per job we are doing.

What I want to accomplish is to create a button that will copy the existing table on to page 2 of my excel workbook.  The table is two columns wide. Therefore I would like to click the button, it copies the table thats on A and B of page 1 onto page 2 A and B. After having done so, I want excel to remember A and B are taken and next time I click the button, it goes in column C and D, then E and F and so on (always on page 2).

to explain why I would like this, I need to order 1000 sq ft of materials, but in sections. only 250 sq ft of materials at a time. So, I want to fill out how much im ordering, click the button and it saves the information of what was ordered on page 2. That way its easy to go back and see what was done, what date, how much was ordered, what is left to order, etc.

I know with numbers it would be easy by just incrementing i by two at every button click, but I dont know how to go about doing this for the excel columns (letters).

Is there some easy command I just cannot find online to do this sort of thing ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You should be able to find places online that answer similar questions. Have you tried anything so far? A recorded macro would actually get you pretty close on this.

Answer (score 0):

What you should learn in VBA and modify in this code below is how to determine the actual range of the table on Sheet1 -- instead of hard-coding it to `"A1:B10"`

**UPDATE**
Not sure why the previous version didn't work for you, but I've updated the code below to store the next column location in a helper cell to see if that works for you.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim srcTable As Range
    Dim dstTable As Range
    Dim nextLoc As Range
    Set srcTable = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10")
    Set nextLoc = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A20")

    '--- if this is your first copy, then cell A1 should be empty
    If IsEmpty(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value) Then
        Set dstTable = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B10")
        nextLoc.Value = 3                           'next location is column 3
    Else
        '--- we're adding the next table...
        Set dstTable = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, nextLoc.Value)
        nextLoc.Value = nextLoc.Value + 2
    End If
    srcTable.Copy dstTable
End Sub
```

Comment: This does copy the table the way I want, but what I'm not sure of is how to make it go two columns over at the end of it. I've tried the code and it just recopies it at the same spot, aka A1:B10 of sheet 2...

Comment: I'm currently cheating doing an IF/Else combo, 10 times, so taht each time it checks if there is something and if there is it moves over by whats in my else. It's not pretty, but I guess it does the trick!

Comment: The magic is in the `End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)` part. This definition of the destination range should pick the first empty column by starting at the farthest right column possible (`IV1`) and then searching back to the left (`xlToLeft`) to find the first non-empty cell --- then offset that non-empty cell one column to the right (`Offset(0,1)`. Each time I ran the code above, the table from Sheet1 was copied to the next empty column on Sheet2. Did you change this line?

Comment: I left it exactly like you did, for some reason it only posts the first column. nothing else appears after I click the button numerous times.

Comment: I updated the code snippet to store the next column location in a helper cell. See if that works for you. I'm not sure why the previous version didn't work.