# vba excel macro button, change only a specific cell, replacing with different data in other sheet

Tags: vba, excel

How do I get a button to change one cell value each time the button is pressed,

lets say cell B5 is the active cell and I want this value to changed every time I click the button based on the values in a different sheet A1:A10,just going down the list.

```
Sub Button2_Click()
Sheets("data").Range("A1:A10").Copy
Sheets("printing").Range("B5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

I want to create a sort of loop, example I'm printing the same file many times but changing the names(in a cell), I have a list of names in a sheet called data, every time I click the button I want the (different sheet called printing) cell B5 to change.

I can simply do this with copy and paste however its about 250 names I was hoping for a simpler solution.

Comment: Each time you click you want to cycle through A1:A10 putting the current value in B5? What should B5 contain? I think you need to clarify the question. Maybe show some data and expected result.

Comment: look into [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29520313/2727437) to see a problem similar to yours

Comment: Consider [edit]ing your post so that the question title is easier to search, for people having similar problems and looking for a solution. Current title isn't quite SEO-optimal, to say the least.

Comment: At the moment you are copying 20 cells from one sheet and pasting starting B5 in a different sheet. How is this different from what you actually want? Show an example because I am still at a loss as to what you hope to see happen as you mention A1:A10, you want to change just B5 and yet you are copying 20 cells A1:A20. And  printing what file?

Comment: QHarr, I simply what the button to change cell B5 based on data on a separate sheet, as you mentioned before like a cycle going through A1:A10, B5 should just contain one cell value at a time (A1) until I click on the button then it should replace the value going down the list (A2) and so on.

Comment: To achieve what you want is quite simple, one approach would be to get the value of B5, search through your A1:A10 range, and return the cell beneath. Add a handler to say if the cell beneath is empty go back to the start of the list. However this isn't a code for me site so a bit of research on searching in vba and using offset and `if` statements and you should be set!

Answer (score 0):

It think that this is about what you are looking for.

The subroutine below sets the value of cell `B5` on sheet 2 to be the value of the cell that corresponds to the index, iterating over down columns then rows (`A1, A2, ... A20, B1, B2, B20` in the example below)

You can learn more about the `static` statement, which makes this work [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/static-statement).

```vb
 Sub iterateStatic(Optional Reset As Boolean = False)
    Static index    As Integer
    Dim fromRng     As Range, _
        targetRng   As Range
    If Reset Then index = 0
    Let index = index + 1
    Set fromRng = Sheets(1).Range("A1:B20")
    Set targetRng = Sheets(2).Range("B5")
    Let targetRng.Value = fromRng.Cells.Item( _
            RowIndex:=index Mod fromRng.Rows.Count, _
            ColumnIndex:=-Int(-index / fromRng.Rows.Count)).Value

'    ''  Debug to show how the function iterates over the range
'
'    Debug.Print fromRng.Cells.Item( _
'            RowIndex:=index Mod fromRng.Rows.Count, _
'            ColumnIndex:=-Int(-index / fromRng.Rows.Count)).Address

End Sub
```